# Is there a way to make a vertical line in Kivy that spans the entire Widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am trying to make a grid-like widget, but I am confused at how to get a vertical line that spans the entire widget. Right now the snippet that I have looks like the following:

```py
SIZE = 2

class TestWidget(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas:
            for i in range(SIZE):
                Line(points=[self.size[0]*(i/SIZE), 0, self.size[0]*(i/SIZE), self.size[1]], color=ListProperty((0,0,1,1)))
```

The quantity of `self.size[i]` only seems to give an integer which is then interpreted by the api as the number of pixels not the size of the canvas. That makes sense, but now I am unsure of where to go now.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MDSeparator from kivymd to do this

```
    MDSeparator:
        orientation:'horizontal'
        height: "10dp"
```

You can also set it to 'vertical', and you can also change the color

A simple example

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv="""
#:import F kivy.factory.Factory

BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'    
    padding:20
    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        MDLabel:
            text:"hello"
        MDCheckbox:
        MDLabel:
            text:"hello"
        MDCheckbox:          
        MDLabel:
            text:"hello"
        MDCheckbox:
                                                    
    MDSeparator:
        orientation:'horizontal'
        height: "10dp"

              
    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        MDLabel:
            text:"hello"
        MDCheckbox:
        MDLabel:
            text:"hello"
        MDCheckbox:          
        MDLabel:
            text:"hello"
        MDCheckbox:     
                                                                            
"""

class Main(MDApp):           
                
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

Main().run()
```